# explode string and add a number? php

Tags: php, explode

i'm realy done with this. My problem is the following:

code:

```
<?php
$highest = 0;
$string = "a.1";

$array = explode(".",$string);
$highest = $array[1];

$final = "secound value is: ".$highest++;

echo $final;
?>
```

All i want is adding something to the number in the $string. So as a result it should echo 2. However it echos 1.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Because it gets incremented after you assign it to the variable. Change post `$highest++` increment, to `++$highest`

Answer (score 4):

Use pre-increment:

```
$final = "secound value is: ".++$highest;
```

More info: [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: what is the difference? I never knew that there is something like this. Thats it. Thank you!

Comment: @Johrdon, The reason is there in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
<?php
$highest = 0;
$string = "a.1";

$array = explode(".",$string);
$highest = $array[1];

$final = "secound value is: ". ++$highest;

echo $final;
?>
```

**The reason is, `$highest++` is the post-increment. It will increment the value only after its usage. And `++$highest` is pre-increment will increment the value first and then use it**

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a post increment. If you do a pre-increment, you will get 2 as your result. Is this what you want?

```
$final = "secound value is: ".++$highest;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to put an answer out of the box. You can save yourself exploding and an array that you may not need/want.

```
$highest = substr($str, 2) + 1;
```

Comment: I tried to use this, but the result is $highest1, the adding operations create a concatenation instead of adding.

Comment: @LuigiLopez I just double checked `$string = "a.1"; $highest = substr($string, 2) + 1; echo $highest;` and echoed `2` out. In php `+` cannot be used for string concatenation only the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between pre-increment and post increment.

```
pre-increment-(++$highest)
   At first increase the value by one then executes the statement.
post-increment-($highest++)
   At first executes the statement then increase the value by one.
```

So in this case You have to use pre-increment.Then line will be executed after increment of the value .

Try this code:

```
<?php
$highest = 0;
$string = "a.1";

$array = explode(".",$string);
$highest = $array[1];

$final = "secound value is: ".++$highest;

echo $final;
?>
```